# Pulling Data from a Infopath form into another custom Sharepoint list column

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, workflow

Right now my company is using office 365 SharePoint online. We are trying to track hours for each project.

I've created an `infopath` form for technicians to fill out their week ending reports.

The technician has a `drop down menu` that shows all the projects. Once they choose the project they would then fill out their task for that project followed by the # of hours they worked on that project.

I am trying to pull that # of hours into a custom list where all the Projects are listed. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Anythony, have you tried googling the subject before posting this question? Have you bought any sharepoint reference manuals? If so, please share what you have found. If not, please start by doing some research.

Comment: @Renaissance I did try to research. I even checked this site before I posted the question.

Comment: please add your search terms (google and SO) into your post. Lets see if we can refine the question. Also, do you have a good Sharepoint reference manual? Are you using MVC or WebForms framework? Do you know them?

Comment: @Renaissance can you recommend me a good SharePoint reference manual? Our company is fairly new with sharepoint and I'm just learning through google/youtube. As for MVC or Webforms Framework, I do not know them. I'm sorry for being a pain

Comment: Also, I recommend you learn asp.net and find out which framework you are using (webforms or MVC). I suspect you are using WebForms, which means you will want to learn asp.net development with WebForms and `code behinds`. Code Behind is probably the way you would solve your current issue.